# C++ Pointer data members: Who should delete them?

Tags: c++

So say I have a class like this:

```
class A {
    public:
        A( SomeHugeClass* huge_object)
            : m_huge_object(huge_object) {}
    private:
        SomeHugeClass* m_huge_object;        
};
```

If someone uses the constructor like this:

```
A* foo = new A(new SomeHugeClass());
```

Who's responsibility is it to call delete on the object newed in the constructor? In this case, the scope in which the A constructor was called can only delete foo since the SomeHugeClass is anonymous.

However, what if someone uses the constructor like this?

```
SomeHugeClass* hugeObj = new SomeHugeClass();
A* foo = new A(hugeObj);
```

Then, the caller can call delete hugeObj at some point, right?

Does this implementation of A leak memory on destruction?

I'm working on a project with a lot of object composition done this way and as much as I would love to use smart pointers, I have to talk to the project leads about changing old code to take advantage of that before I can.

Comment: You need to initialise `hugeObj` in your last code snippet; otherwise, chances are you will run into undefined behaviour sometime when you use `foo`.

Comment: No one can say who should delete the pointer members in your case: we lack of some context to answer reliably. I think it depends on what does your class and what it represent. It could be a class that refers to some external data and for whose documentation specifies that its lifetime must not exceed the lifetime of the referred data. Or it could just take ownership.

Comment: Who should delete it depends on who owns it. Unfortunately your constructor lacks the symantic clarity on who owns the object being passed in (this is why passing pointers is a bad idea). If you want the object to own the pointer the constructor should take a std::auto_ptr<> (this indicates a transfer of ownership). If you want to indicate that the object is a shared resource then the constructor should take a shared_ptr<>. If you want to indicate that object does not take ownership the constructor should take a reference.

Comment: In some cases in the codebase, we're passing pointers to large objects that are large subsystems of the application. I know in that case I wouldn't delete them, because my class has no idea if the application needs to die yet. (Nor should it be responsible for general cleanup.)

However, we also have a class that generates words based on some rules, and its generally created on the fly and used like new SomeHugeClass() in my original post. 

However, I could see a case where the caller, say, instantiates two A's with the same SomeHugeClass, so one deleting it would screw with the other.

Comment: Just a bit more:

My first instinct was to just use a shared_ptr and get back to solving larger problems. Unfortunately, even though this is an open-source project, introducing dependencies on boost means chatting about it for a bit. I'm glad I'm getting a lot of good answers so I can make a good case for it, though. Lastly, what would passing by const reference gain me in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I try to follow this simple rule whenever it is possible: The one who calls `new` should call `delete` as well. Otherwise the code soon becomes too messy to keep track of what is deleted and what is not.

In your case, if A::A receives the pointer, it must not delete it. Think of this simple case:

```
SomeHugeClass* hugeObj = new SomeHugeClass();
A * a1 = new A(hugeObj);
A * a2 = new A(hugeObj);
```

Class A can not *know* who else is using that pointer!

If you want class A to take care of the pointer, it should create it itself.

Of course, you could handle both cases, but that might be an overkill, something like this:

```
A::A() : own_huge_object(true) {
    m_huge_object = new SomeHugeClass();
}
A::A(SomeHugeClass * huge_object ) : own_huge_object(false) {
    m_huge_object = huge_object;
}
A::~A() { if(own_huge_object) delete m_huge_object; }
```

Comment: +1 for "The one who calls new should call delete as well". I think this makes things more elegant. However, I have to admit that `Qt` doesn't respect this rule, but deals with it pretty well.

Comment: If we followed this rule consistently, we'd have to throw out `auto_ptr`!  I think this proves that, while it has some validity, it can be taken too far.  In some cases, you *want* to transfer ownership.

Answer (score 3):

In your example caller should be responsible for deleting `huge_object` because constructor could throw exception and destructor of `A` will not be called. And your implementation has a memory leak since nobody calls `delete` now.

You could use [`shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) as follows:

```
class A {
    public:
        A( shared_ptr<SomeHugeClass> huge_object)
            : m_huge_object(huge_object) {}
    private:
        shared_ptr<SomeHugeClass> m_huge_object;        
};
```

In this case you shouldn't care about deleting `SomeHugeClass`.

Comment: I don't agree regarding whose responsibility it should be, but I do agree that using smart pointers is the best answer.

Comment: Please no `shared_ptr` by default! Shared ownership should be a conscious decision. It's better to use a `std::unique_ptr` or a `boost::scoped_ptr` if you don't have access to C++0x yet.

Comment: Every decision should be conscious. It's a bad idea just to copy-paste code from Internet (even from SO). I've added the link, so OP could read more about `shared_ptr`.

Comment: This article (http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/39071/1954) suggests that `auto_ptr` should be replaced by `unique_ptr`, which makes me glad I generally endorsed smart pointers as a concept without specifying an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this line below

```
A* foo = new A(new SomeHugeClass());
```

**not** to result in memory leak, you can make sure to free memory pointed to by **m_huge_object** in the destructor of class A.

The class A definition can look something like below:

```
class A {
  public:
    A(SomeHugeClass* huge_object)
        : m_huge_object(huge_object) {}
    ~A() { delete m_huge_object; }
  private:
    SomeHugeClass* m_huge_object;        
};
```

What I don't like about the above is that I prefer whoever allocates memory should also be the one responsible to free that memory.  Also, there's the problem that Kirill pointed out. So keep your definition of class A, and the code can be as simple as:

```
SomeHugeClass* hugeObj = new SomeHugeClass();
A* foo = new A(hugeObj); 
//some code
delete hugeObj;
delete foo;
```

Comment: This is not good.  It may well be that the destructor of `foo` has to reference `hugeObj`, so you've just caused an exception.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Which one?  If you take the second version, it's the same code that the poster had in the first place, i.e. no destructor (which is what I said).

Comment: You effectively stated that, in the second version, `~A` does not delete `m_hugeObj`.  You then showed `hugeObj` being destructed *after* `foo`, even though `foo` was constructed second.  This is very wrong.  I gave an example of why it is wrong: `foo` has `m_hugeObj`, which points to the same instance as `hugeObj` does, and may be expected to use this pointer for its entire lifespan.  Despite this, you pull the rug out from under `foo` by deleting `hugeObj`, leaving its `m_hugeObj` pointing to an invalid location.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  I was pointing that if the poster keeps his original code, that's the code with no destructor, then he would have to delete each variable that he newed.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a design problem. Traditionnaly, when you pass non-const pointers to a constructor, the object should release the pointer. Pass a const reference if you intend to keep a copy.

An alternate design is something along these lines: SomeHugeClass typically is not that huge (eg. a pointer), but owns a huge amount of memory:

```
class A
{
    SomeHugeClass m_;

public:
    A(SomeHugeClass x) { m_.swap(x); }
};
```

This design is possible if SomeHugeClass implements an efficient swap (swapping the pointers). The constructor makes a copy of `x` before swapping it into `m_`, and if you pass a temporary object to the constructor, the copy may be (and usually will be) elided by the compiler.

Note that SomeHugeClass can be replaced here by `smart_pointer<SomeHugeClass>` giving the semantics you want when you pass smart_pointer(new SomeHugeClass()) to the constructor, since it is temporary.

EDIT (for clarity...):
Final code may look like

```
class A
{
    smart_ptr<SHC> m_;

public:
    A(smart_ptr<SHC> x) { m_.swap(x); }
};
```

which has the required behavior when you call `A(new SHC(...))` (no copy, and deletion when A gets destructed), and when you call `A(smart_ptr<SHC>(a))` (copy of `a` is performed, and released when A gets destructed).